# How would I go about comparing two character that will convert to the same character?

Tags: java, character-encoding, switch-statement

So basically, I want to use the switch statement. I have a chart for each encoded character that a user will enter. However, each uppercase character and lowercase character has the same meaning. I find it unnecessary to copy each switch statement and revise the same thing. So how would I come about this?

Comment: You can use `switch`'s fall-through. So something along the lines of `switch (character) { case 'a': case 'A': /* code */ break; case 'b': case 'B': ... }`

Comment: You can also just uppercase the char you pass into the switch "switch(Character.toUpperCase(yourChar)) {...}", then you only have to define the cases for uppercase.

Comment: @911DidBush That's actually a good point, and probably less error-prone. My example is only good in case something changes and a lowercase character stops meaning the same as its corresponding uppercase character.

Comment: Just one additional hint: In addition to converting user input to uppercase, you can use a `java.util.Map` that maps all possible uppercase characters to the corresponding chart. Then you can simple lookup your chart instead of writing one huge switch statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`toUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29):

> Converts the character argument to uppercase using case mapping information from the UnicodeData file.

```
switch (Character.toUpperCase(character)) {
    case 'A':
        // code ...
        break;
    case 'B':
        // code ...
        break;
    ...
    default:
        // default code
}
```

Comment: I find this method much suitable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `switch`'s fall-through. So something along the lines of:

```
switch (character) {
case 'a': // fall through to next case
case 'A':
    // code ...
    break;
case 'b': // fall through to next case
case 'B':
    // code ...
    break;
...
default:
    // default code
}
```

What's happening here is that, because the `switch` continues executing code once it finds a matching `case` until it runs into a `break;`, if your character is an 'a', since there isn't a `break;`, the program will continue with the lines of code in the `case` for 'A'. Same for 'b', 'c', etc.

In this situation, I absolutely agree that using `Character.toUpperCase()` is more appropriate. Using fall-through here would only really help if requirements change such that a lowercase character no longer means the same as its uppercase. In any case, [fall-through does have its uses](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/116221) and is a useful construct to know about.